# Scatter plot throws TypeError

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, scatter-plot

I am trying following code:

```
from sklearn.cross_validation import train_test_split
from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler
scaler=StandardScaler()
from sklearn.linear_model import LogisticRegression
from sklearn import linear_model
model = linear_model.LogisticRegression()
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from sklearn.metrics import mean_squared_error, r2_score

X=scaler.fit_transform(X)

X_train,X_test,y_train,y_test=train_test_split(X,y,test_size=0.2)

model.fit(X_train,y_train)
# Make predictions using the testing set
powerOutput_y_pred = model.predict(X_test)
print (powerOutput_y_pred)
# The coefficients
print('Coefficients: \n', model.coef_)
# The mean squared error
print("Mean squared error: %.2f"
      % mean_squared_error(y_test, powerOutput_y_pred))
# Explained variance score: 1 is perfect prediction
print('Variance score: %.2f' % r2_score(y_test, powerOutput_y_pred))

plt.scatter(X_test, y_test,  color='black')
plt.plot(X_test, powerOutput_y_pred, color='blue', linewidth=3)
plt.xticks(())
plt.yticks(())
plt.show()
```

But i am getting the following error for the scatter plot:

```
ValueError: x and y must be the same size
```

If i run df.head(), i get following table:

[df structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mSMvl.png)

The features X and y are as below:

```
X=df.values[:,[0,1,2,3,4,5,7]]
y=df.values[:,6]
```

Running X.shape gives (25,7) and y.shape gives (25, ) as output. So how to fix this shape mismatch?

Comment: What do you expect the scatter plot to look like? That is, what relationship are you attempting to plot?

Comment: I am trying to follow this:
http://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/linear_model/plot_ols.html
But this has used one feature only. I am trying to use many 7 features in X.

Comment: Best answer turned out to be even simpler than I thought. If you just replace `scatter` with `plot` then everything should work as is. If you set a few options correctly (`ls`, `marker`, and `ms`), calling `plot` will produce a scatter plot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Simplest answer

Just use `plot` instead of `scatter`:

```
plt.plot(X_test, y_test, ls="none", marker='.', ms=12)
```

This will plot the different sets of x data all using the same single set of y data. This assumes that `x.shape == (n,d)` and `y.shape == (n,)`, as in your question above.

## Simple answer

Loop over the columns of your x values, and call `scatter` once for each column:

```
colors = plt.cm.viridis(np.linspace(0.0, 1.0, features))
for xcol,c in zip(X_test.T, colors):
    plt.scatter(xcol, y_test, c=c)
```

Setting `c` with the array `colors` will make it so that each feature is plotted as a different color on the scatter plot. If do you want them all to be black, just replace the colors stuff above with `c='black'`

## details

`scatter` expects one list of x values and one list of y values. It's simplest if the x and y list are 1D. However you can also plot multiple sets of x and y data stored in 2D arrays, if those arrays have matching shape.

From the [Matplotlib docs](https://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.scatter.html):

> Fundamentally, scatter works with 1-D arrays; x, y, s, and c may be input as 2-D arrays, but within scatter they will be flattened.

A bit vague, but a [dive into the Matplotlib source code](https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/blob/3664c83425f86cbe4a2a5133514cee2366b2bfd1/lib/matplotlib/axes/_axes.py#L4002) confirms that the shapes of x and y have to match exactly. The code that handles shapes for `plot` is more flexible, so for that function you can away get with using one set of y data for many sets of x data.

Normally `plot` plots lines instead of dots, but you can turn lines off by setting `ls` (ie `linestyle`), and you can turn dots on by setting `marker`. `ms` (ie `markersize`) controls the size of the dots.

## example

The example you posted above won't run (`X` and `y` aren't defined), but here's a complete example with output:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib import cm

from sklearn import datasets
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split

d = datasets.load_diabetes()
features = d.data.shape[1]

X = d.data[:50,:]
Y = d.target[:50]

sample_weight = np.random.RandomState(442).rand(Y.shape[0])

# split train, test for calibration
X_train, X_test, Y_train, Y_test, sw_train, sw_test = \
    train_test_split(X, Y, sample_weight, test_size=0.9, random_state=442)

# use the plot function instead of scatter
# plot one set of y data against several sets of x data
plt.plot(X_test, Y_test, ls="none", marker='.', ms=12)

# call .scatter() multiple times in a loop
#colors = plt.cm.viridis(np.linspace(0.0, 1.0, features))
#for xcol,c in zip(X_test.T, colors):
#    plt.scatter(xcol, Y_test, c=c)
```

output:

[image]

Comment: The simple answer seems to work fine but for the simple answer, i can see that y.shape is still the same as y.T.shape so its not working